# What is this immovable icon in my macOS menu bar?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I do not recognize it; reverse image search produces nothing.

[image]

Command + click has no effect; nothing appears on regular click either. It appears whenever LibreOffice is open.

Comment: How about some context.  It's is very, very, rare for an application just just put an icon out there without some contet or even textual help when you hover over it.   What happens if you click on it?- you're not going to break anything!

Comment: Have you checked for updates to LibreOffice?  Also, what LibreOffice app are you using when this appears, or does it appear any time that you are running the program?